# First storyboard To display

Tags: storyboard, swift4, xcode9.3

I am using swift4 and xcode9.3.

I want to know how can the application determine which storyboard to display if it has many of them.

I know the flow of running application in swift4, it will start with the launch View then it will run "appdeleget.swift" file then will display the storyboard and start with the initial view controller and put it as window.rootViewController. But the missing thing is how the application detect the storyboard to start with it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Navigator -> Select Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface -> Select one of your story boards

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, 
will the application know the Main interface before running?

Comment: yup and the main UI loads before app delegate, check this workflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nIFo.png